# mongodb query result from multiple collections and save to one

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

For example:

1.Using find, test each collection:

```
var objIdMin = ObjectId(Math.floor((new Date('2016/05/01 00:00:00'))/1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000");
var objIdMax = ObjectId(Math.floor((new Date('2016/05/11 00:00:00'))/1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000");

db.getCollection('google').find({ _id:{$gt: objIdMin, $lt: objIdMax}, 'result.text':/phone/}).count();
```

google collection result count is 50.

```
db.getCollection('apple').find({ _id:{$gt: objIdMin, $lt: objIdMax}, 'result.text':/phone/}).count();
```

apple collection result count is 100.

2.then I turn to achieve my purpose:

```
var cols = db.getCollectionNames();
var objIdMin = ObjectId(Math.floor((new Date('2016/05/01 00:00:00'))/1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000");
var objIdMax = ObjectId(Math.floor((new Date('2016/05/11 00:00:00'))/1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000");

var cols_in = ['google', 'apple'];
for (var i=0; i<cols_in.length; i++){
    db.getCollection(cols_in[i]).aggregate([ { $match: { _id:{$gt: objIdMin, $lt: objIdMax}, 'result.text':/phone/}}, { $out: "target" } ]);
};
```

The count of `target collection`'s result is equal to 100(same as `apple collection`), so the later collection will overwrite the former, how to solve this?

**Edit**:
I find that is due to:

> **Replace Existing Collection**
>
> If the collection specified by the $out operation already exists, then
>   upon completion of the aggregation, the $out stage atomically replaces
>   the existing collection with the new results collection. The $out
>   operation does not change any indexes that existed on the previous
>   collection. If the aggregation fails, the $out operation makes no
>   changes to the pre-existing collection.

So, the only way is to foreach every record and insert to another collection?

Answer (score 0):

as per comment -> there is no UNION ALL in mongo, which could merge outputs from many queries into one logical piece.

So you solution to iterate collections with for is a very good approach, but with  every pass you are overwriting output collection named **target** in your example

To solve this problem in `for` loop save aggregation 'output' as an array, and then insert.

Please see snipped bellow:

```
for (var i = 0; i < cols_in.length; i++) {
    var documents = db.getCollection(cols_in[i]).aggregate([{
                $match : {
                    _id : {
                        $gt : objIdMin,
                        $lt : objIdMax
                    },

                }
            } 
        ]).toArray();

        db.target.insert(documents)
};
```

Comment: I am asking a way without using for loop.